# MySQL + Rails ordering by count of found keywords

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, innodb

I have a Faq class in MySQL/InnoDB that has instance keywords like

```
apple,juice,fruit
```

I have a class method

```
def self.find_by_string string = nil
 unless string.present?
   return
 end

 keywords = string.gsub(/(\,|\.|\s)/, " ").split.uniq.join("|")

 Faq.find(
          :all, 
          :conditions => "keywords like '%" + keywords.gsub(/\|/, "%' or keywords like '%") + "%'"
        )
end
```

I need to order the result of find by the count of found keywords in it. I mean, if SQL found 4 keywords it must be higher in results than 3 keywords.  How to do that?

Comment: Instead of doing `string.gsub(/(\,|\.|\s)/, " ").split`, you could skip a step and pass a parameter to `split` reducing it to `string.split(/[\,|\.|\s]/)`

Comment: I know man, but there is some special feature why I've do that, doesn't matter. But thanks.